# Why is array access operator ([]) on objects not an error?

Tags: typescript, tslint

While refactoring my code, I stumbled upon a weird behaviour of the TypeScript compiler which I don't understand.

```
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

let a: IPoint = { x: 5, y: 10 };
let b = a[0];
console.log(b);
```

When compiling this code, I'd expect the compiler to throw an error because of accessing a key of `a` that definitely does not exist (at compile-time).

Why is that? Is there alternatively a TSLint option I'm not aware of that marks `[]` being used on objects as error/warning?

Best regards and thanks in advance

Comment: bracket operator is the "escape out of types" operator in TypeScript but you can disable this behavior with `noImplicitAny` as mentioned by Titian. I've had to use it to hack something more than once, I'm ashamed to say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend turning on the `--strict` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  This option turns on a bunch of extra checking that is invaluable in catching errors.  In your case, the particular checking you want is done via the `--noImplicitAny` option:

> `--noImplicitAny`: Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.

If you turn that on, you'll see the following error appear:

```
let b = a[0]; // error!
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'IPoint' has no index signature.
```

You may find that if you turn on `--strict` mode, lots of other errors show up.  That's annoying, but generally those are good errors you should deal with, and even when false positives appear, handling those errors will make your code better.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 3):

With default compiler settings typescript will allow indexing operations on any object with any key (and the result will be of type `any`). To make this an error use the `noImplicitAny` compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `[]` is not *only* an array index operator, it is also a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), which means it can be used to access properties of an object, e.g.

```
const animal = {
  legCount: 4
};

console.log(animal.legCount); // 4
console.log(animal['legCount']); // 4
```

As [discussed here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7733#issuecomment-203645506), TypeScript implicitly gives all indexes the type `any`:

> JavaScript allows to index into any object. TypeScript compiler can not statically know type checked all these, e.g. `var name = getName(); x[name];`. so it gives it the type `any`.

To add some level of protection, you could try adding an index signature and specify the expected types.

```
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    [key: string]: number; // This object will contain only number properties.
}
```